# Monkey V Monkey (MvM) not working?

Tags: mobile, bloons-monkey-city

In BMCM (Bloons Monkey City Mobile) for Android, when I send bloons to attack other players, the game chooses a random player as my target, asks me the kind of waves to send and then gives me a couple Bloonstones for the attack. I never get notified about how did the attack end, nor I ever get any loot.

Is that because the target player is inactive and never defends himself from the attack, hence it never happens? I've noticed I've never ever have received an attack, and on Contested Territory I'm almost the only one which does even try, as if no one is playing the game.

Has anyone ever launched a successful attack? Is MvM useless on Android? I send attack after attack getting no loot, but having to build new facilities and research new technologies from time to time in order to send the next attack. Is it a waste of money?

Answer (score 2):

In my time on Bloons Monkey City on Android, I've found roughly 95% of people do not attempt to defend against attacks.  There's a timer that will eventually time out, (I believe it's around 24 hours) and when it does you should get a message stating that they failed to defend.  When that happens, you'll get a "win" bonus, which includes a few bloonstones.

Thus, I will send attacks ASAP when my bloontonium is full, just for the chance at more bloonstones.

Contested territory is a bit more of a fight for me at least.  It's definitely worth doing, so long as you are good enough to get at least one of the rewards.  It's an excellent way to get free Monkey Knowledge packs, and there are Bloonstone rewards as well.

Players aren't placed into a contested territory until they load the contested territory screen, so technically those people have to be playing.  However, it might be that they never make it to the first milestone, or they load it and see someone else's progress and decide not to even try.

Comment: When I didn't 100% know how CT worked, I reached the minimum wave needed to capture it as I thought when bloons recaptured it, they would top my record and I had to go further (which is false). However, when I did that, someone would capture it sooner or later (but only one among the 5 I'm matched against). Now that I go until the ZOMG no one does, so I guess they play less than me and, despite being my level, they give up as soon as they see wave 29. I guess they are active, but not very much. Always worth doing as you gain money while you occupy the territory anyway.

Comment: Several days have passed since my first MvM and I've received no loot nor message, but I always get a few BS in the exact moment I send the attack. Is that normal?

Comment: @JeffreyLebowski, yeah, for CT it resets to "nobody controls it" and you can just retake it.  You can tap on other players' villages to see how high they've made it.  I *think* if you win a lot of CT they will start matching you up against harder folks.  RE: the MvM, I think I always get a message after 24 hours, but I send so many and have to dismiss so many "Victory!" and "You lost!" messages that I don't keep track :P

Answer (score -1):

they need to fix this, even to this day. its either 1 of 2 things are happening

1: attacking pacifist mode not working:
what I mean by that is pacifist mode DOES work, but when people are attacking other people, the people who are on pacifist mode can be an option to attack, but because this person is on pacifist mode, thus they don't receive the attack at all.
this could be solved if they fixed the attacks so they don't include the people in pacifist mode

2: inactive user: just like the problem, the user doesn't play this game anymore, so they are probably stacked with hundreds of attacks that have never actually been received before.
this could be solved if every inactive player within a time limit would be entered into pacifist mode automatically. (I don't know if this is already true)

personally if I think that assuming that problem number 1 isn't the problem, the my solution to be either be automatically enable pacifist mode after a certain time, or if there is an incoming attack, and the user still hasn't touched it within a week, its a automatic win. but T|I think it would be better if the devs fixed the matchmaking to be like the matchmaking in CT, where it only find the active players who have pacifist mode off